# load 3 (or more) html page in one webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

suppose i have 5 html pages, and i want to load 3 of them in one `webview` so that they are vertically below each other. (they can be accessed by vertical scrolling) is that possible? and how?

**NOTE 1:** i'm thinking of adding `webview` s to main view in runtime for another pages, but is there better and efficient way?

**NOTE 2**: the main goal is above one, but as alternative i tried overriding `onOverScrolled()` and `onScrollChanged()` to find out end of scrolling and then load another page, but this way has it's own problems.

Answer (score 0):

Put the webviews ionto a linear layout which has a scrollview parent, and vertical orientation, and set on webvies: webView.setFocusable(false)

Comment: this isn't answer to main question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load 3 pages in one webview then having the webview load some html that loads those pages as iframes might be the way to go.